# Java / Libgdx Timer stops when window is not anymore in focus

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, libgdx

i have got the following iusse. My timer works well until my game window is out of focus, right after that it stops and only resumes when it is in focus again. While it isnt in focus it does everything without calling the timer.

Heres my timer method :

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void update(){

    if(game.hostServer || !game.hostServer){

        packetUpdate.scheduleTask(new Task() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                gameScreen.playerEntity.updateNetworkPositions();

                gameScreen.playerEntity.updateNetworkStates();

                if(game.hostServer && gameScreen.launcher.network.client.isConnected()){

                    for(int i = 0; i < gameScreen.enemyEntityList.size(); i++){

                        EnemyEntity entity = gameScreen.enemyEntityList.get(i);

                        entity.listId = i;

                        if(game.hostServer){

                            System.err.println("Sending packets");

                        }

                        entity.updateNetworkPositions();

                        entity.updateNetworkStates();

                    }

                }

            }

        }, 0.05f);

    }               

}
```

That update method is called in my render thread right here :

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void render(final float delta) {

        lightManager.doStep(delta); 

        GdxAI.getTimepiece().update(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        launcher.update();      

}
```

I already searched for an answer, but didnt found any. There was one guy on reddit with the same problem but he didnt ever got an answer. Can someone help me to solve this ? :)

Comment: For something to happen while the game is out of focus, you need to create a Service in Android. To get that to work with LibGDX, you would need to create a Service-creating interface, for which the Android specific code can have an implementation that is passed to your game constructor. You will need to read the Android documentation on Services.

Comment: Thats right, but it wont even work on my desktop :/ The timer stopps, soon as the window isnt in focus

Comment: I don't see where you started another thread.

Comment: I searched a little bit, its because i missed something in my config. Its ok now :)

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm having the same issue..

Comment: @Aeonia finnaly I asked the libgdx team, they told me I should use the normal Java timers or selfmade ones. There's no way to do this with gdx tiners :/

Comment: Could you share a bit of code please..? I just need my timer( in render) to update itself while app is out of focus or rather when I come back to the app to update itself with the elapsed time.. Thanks